# Run program on iPhone with flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Hello I am having a problem running my program on my iphone, when I put "run" it gives me this error.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

error:

```
You can connect to your Apple Developer account by signing in with your Apple ID
in Xcode and create an iOS Development Certificate as well as a Provisioning 
Profile for your project by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- In the 'General' tab, make sure a 'Development Team' is selected. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again
  5- Trust your newly created Development Certificate on your iOS device
     via Settings > General > Device Management > [your new certificate] > Trust

For more information, please visit:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/
  AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Finished with error: No development certificates available to code sign app for device deployment
```

> when I try to enter this link it says it is unavailable: enter image description here"https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/"

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76,
    locale pt-PT)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got half of the link. Try the full link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Also, you might want to check official flutter guidelines for clear instructions:

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices